# Why does computer only occasionally have trouble posting/booting?

Tags: boot, post

I'm having a very interesting problem with my computer. Every one in a while (around every 5-10 times i boot the computer), my computer will do one of the 3 things:

1. Boot and stay stuck at the BIOS screen
2. Flash a bunch of colors and go to black (never booting after this happens)
3. It will turn on, and after 1 second shut off, then restart and work just fine.

After doing some research, I thought the problem might be USB or sata cables, so I opened up the case and removed them and put them back in. Then, it started perpetually shutting off and coming back on, not working at all! I determined without a doubt the problem was a bad stick of RAM, and once I removed it my computer works like it did before with the first couple of problems popping up every once in a while.

I have since tested to see if it was the RAM slot on the motherboard (it wasn't, it was the RAM), and I also ran a memtest and a processor diagnostic test from intel, and both seem to be fine. I'm a little hesitant about returning the motherboard just yet, because I want to be more sure about what's wrong with my computer, plus it normally works fine (and im not worried about it when i have to forcibly shut the computer off since I have a SSD and Windows 10 seems to fix its filesystem errors by itself...please correct me if I should be more worried about having to shut off the computer)

Can you all point me in any further direction, or make any recommendations about what I should do here?

Comment: It could be a faulty (blown caps?) or under powered PSU - are you able to test it against another (ideally more powerful) PSU,  ?    If not, can you load-shed some stuff on your computer (unplug hard drives,  discrete graphics card) and see if it starts reliably ?

Comment: Have you done any overclocking of CPU or memory? And, even if you haven't, is your RAM configuration correct? I've had a computer incorrectly detect RAM timings which led to system instability.

Comment: never heard of ram configuration, ill look into it, the problem with testing this is that it only every once in a while has a problem